# Why My Adsense Account is not accepted

Tags: google-adsense, advertising, google-adsense-policies

I have created a blog on blogger few days ago and created two blog entries on it. when i try creating AdSense account with blog's address it does not accept the application due to PageType. i have searched around on the net and found that its probably due to duplicate or insufficient content on the blog but either of my blog entry is more than 2,000 words and i have literally typed 80 percent of its content with only few code blocks copied from other sites. Below is content of email i received as response to my application.

Hello,

Thank you for your interest in Google AdSense. Unfortunately, after
reviewing your application, we're unable to accept you into AdSense at
this time.

We did not approve your application for the reasons listed below.

Issues:
- Page Type

---

Further detail:
Page Type: In order to participate in Google AdSense, publishers' websites
and application information must satisfy the following guidelines:

- Your website must be your own top-level domain (www.example.com and not
  www.example.com/mysite).
- You must provide accurate personal information with your application
  that matches the information on your domain registration.
- Your website must contain substantial, original content.
- Your site must comply with Google AdSense program policies:
  https://www.google.com/adsense/policies" which include Google's webmaster
  quality guidelines:
  http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=35769#quality
  .

If your site satisfies the above criteria in the future, please resubmit
your application and we'll review it as soon as possible

My Personal credentials are also same as they appear in my google account. i can't figure out the problem. Any Help/Suggestion is highly appreciated.
regards

Comment: Does your site meet the criteria listed above? It probably doesn't which is why they rejected it. You need to improve your site to meet that criteria if you want to accept Adsense on it.

Comment: A site created three days ago containing two blog entries is unlikely to "contain substantial, original content" in Google's eyes. I'd suggest posting a bit more before resubmitting your AdSense application.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Your website must contain substantial,
>   original content.

I just checked out your website. You have two blog posts. That fails to meet the criteria of having "substantial original content". You need to write a lot more content before you can have adsense on your website.