# Why is my site not approved by Google Adsense?

Tags: google, google-adsense, google-search-console

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why My Adsense Account is not accepted](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/14256/why-my-adsense-account-is-not-accepted)

I tried to submit my site for google adsense and it was rejected twice saying that it is not following google guidelines. I request that anybody go through my website and post your answer here as to why my site is rejected. I have Adword account which runs everyday.  My site is 
[Sulabhloan.com](http://sulabhloan.com)

I will post further details if you ask.

Comment: Google should list the reason for the rejection in the email they send to you, but the most common one is that your site needs to contain substantial original content to be accepted. In this case, it looks like your site doesn't contain enough useful original content for Google to build an AdSense profile and show ads inline with your content. You might consider starting a blog, building up a list of useful articles, and then applying to put Google AdSense on that.

Comment: @Nick , Yes But google given very General reasons which i failed to notice in My Site . this web site is about Loans in Bangalore ..if possible , i request you to go to the website and browse content and if any major wron gin that pleae let me know i will correct and resubmit ...

Comment: Your website does not offer 'substantial original content.' See [this answer.](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/14256/why-my-adsense-account-is-not-accepted)

Comment: @Nick , i want to drag further in these , substantial original Content means should i use more Texts in the Home page and Inner pages ..is this you mean ??

Comment: At the moment, your website has about 6 pages. All of them use the same template and include nearly identical content. That's not 'substantial original content'. In addition, your site probably breaks Google's [Webmaster Guidelines](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=35769#quality) because it is not a 'useful, information-rich site'. It is simply a sales page. Again, if you want to use AdSense, I suggest that you create a separate blog with useful content.

Comment: @Nick , Thank You very Much ... simple and exclusive suggestions ..  i appreciate you to spend your precious  time on my site and i will correct the things you mentioned will resubmit .. Thank You .